# How to persist Checkbox checked state in ExpandableListView?

Tags: android, checkbox, expandablelistview, expandablelistadapter

i am using `Expandablelistview` with multiple `checkbox` inside child,but i am not able to maintain checked states of `checkbox` inside each group.i tried and searched a lot and got some code but still getting this issues.i think sometimes i am not getting right child position or group position due to which couldn't persist their checked state.i have already waste our 2 days in this troubleshooting. so Your help would really saved my coming days and appreciated.This is My Adapter Code :

```
    public class SubItemAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

    private List<String> titleList;
    private List<ItemDetailMapper> number_items;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private HashMap<String,List<ItemDetailMapper>> childlist;
    Context context;
    FontFamily fontFamily;
    private RadioButton mSelectedRB;
    private int mSelectedPosition = -1;
    ArrayList<Integer> integerArrayList;
    boolean [] checkedPosition;
    boolean [] checkParentPosition;
    HashMap<Integer, boolean []> check;
    ImageLoader imageLoader;
    DisplayImageOptions displayImageOptions;
    int count = 0;
    Integer numberof_items;
    List<Integer> child_position;
    List<Integer> parent_position;
    private HashMap<Integer,boolean[]> itemCheck;
    public SubItemAdapter(ItemDetailActivity context, List<String> headings_itemList, HashMap<String, List<ItemDetailMapper>> child_itemList, List<ItemDetailMapper> child) {
        this.context = context;
        this.titleList = headings_itemList;
        this.childlist = child_itemList;
        this.number_items = child;
        fontFamily = new FontFamily(context);
        integerArrayList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
        checkParentPosition = new boolean[titleList.size()];
        check = new HashMap<Integer, boolean []>();
        child_position = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        parent_position = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        itemCheck = new HashMap<Integer, boolean[]>();
        displayImageOptions = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
                .showImageOnLoading(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_gallery)
                .showImageForEmptyUri(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_gallery)
                .showImageOnFail(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_gallery)
                .cacheInMemory(true)
                .cacheOnDisk(true)
                .considerExifParams(true)
                .bitmapConfig(Bitmap.Config.RGB_565)
                .build();

    }


    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
        return titleList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
        return childlist.get(titleList.get(groupPosition)).size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
        return titleList.get(groupPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return childlist.get(this.titleList.get(groupPosition)).get(childPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
        return groupPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return childPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
       String listTitle = (String) getGroup(groupPosition);

        CoachHolder holder = null;
        View row = convertView;

        if (row == null) {
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            row = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.shopping_list_item_parentrow, null);
            holder = new CoachHolder(row);
            row.setTag(holder);
        }else{
            holder =(CoachHolder)row.getTag();
        }
        String numberofitems = 
        number_items.get(groupPosition).getSubProductItemNumber();
        numberof_items =    
     Integer.valueOf(number_items.get(groupPosition).getSubProductItemNumber());
        Boolean requiredproduct = 
     number_items.get(groupPosition).getSubProductRequired();

             return row;
    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition,int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ItemDetailMapper expandedListData = (ItemDetailMapper)getChild(groupPosition,childPosition);

       // final String expandedListText = (String) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);
       // checkedPosition = new boolean[childlist.get(titleList.get(groupPosition)).size()];
        ChildHolder holder = null;
        View row = convertView;
        LinearLayout lnrLayout = null;

       final int chl = childPosition;
       final int grp= groupPosition;


        if (row == null) {
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            row = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.sub_item_row, null);
            holder = new ChildHolder(row);
            row.setTag(R.layout.sub_item_row,holder);

        }else{
            holder =(ChildHolder)row.getTag(R.layout.sub_item_row);

        }

         if (itemCheck.containsKey(grp)){
             boolean getChecked[] = itemCheck.get(grp);
             holder.checkBox.setChecked(getChecked[chl]);
             notifyDataSetChanged();
         }else{
             boolean getChecked[] = new boolean[getChildrenCount(grp)];
             itemCheck.put(grp,getChecked);
             holder.checkBox.setChecked(false);
             notifyDataSetChanged();
         }

         holder.checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null);



        holder.checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
             @Override
             public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {
                 if (b){
                     boolean getChecked[] = itemCheck.get(grp);
                     getChecked[chl] = b;
                     itemCheck.put(grp,getChecked);
                     notifyDataSetChanged();

                 }else{
                     boolean getChecked[] = itemCheck.get(grp);
                     getChecked[chl] = b;
                     itemCheck.put(grp,getChecked);
                     notifyDataSetChanged();
                 }
             }
         });

        holder.child_tv1.setText(expandedListData.getSubproductItemName());
        holder.item_price.setText("("+"$ "+ 
        expandedListData.getSubProductItemPrice()+")");
        imageLoader.displayImage(expandedListData.getSubProductItemImage(), 
        holder.imagev1, displayImageOptions);

        return row;
    }



    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return true;
    }


    static class CoachHolder {

        TextView textView1;
        ImageView imageView;

        //TextView descriptions
        public CoachHolder(View v)
        {

            textView1 = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.parenttext);
            imageView = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.expandable_identifier);

        }

    }



    //CUSTOM Child CLASS for listgroup
    static class ChildHolder {

        ImageView imagev1;
        TextView child_tv1,item_price;

     //   RadioGroup radioGroup;
        CheckBox checkBox;


        //TextView descriptions
        public ChildHolder(View v)
        {
            item_price = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.item_price);
            imagev1 = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.imageView20);
            child_tv1 = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.textView164);
            checkBox = (CheckBox) v.findViewById(R.id.radioButton5);

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: You forgot to tell us how you tried to tackle the problem. Do you expect us to discover that from your code? We will not.

Comment: Sorry for inconvenience @greenapps ,Actually we are trying to store each checked state of child checkbox against group position using HashMap itemCheck so that we couldn't face reuseability issues.

Comment: Actually when we click on first group and check their child checked box after that when we expand second group and checked one or two of their child then  first group child position get lost . so i want to maintain the checked states.